# How to collect HTTP data in Wireshark from a remote Linux host?

Tags: linux, http, wireshark, tcpdump

I am trying to collect HTTP requests and responses from a remote host using *Wireshark* using SSH tunnel. So I have **Windows host** with **Wireshark** on it, and **Linux** host with **tcpdump** on it and a web server listening on port 5000.

I execute tcpdump on the linux host and try to get the output on the windows host. I can see the flow of the packets pretty well, but I see **NO HTTP**!

When I try to send any request to the web host I see some tcp packets flowing in and out, but no HTTP. It must be mentioned the I see the HTTP requests and responses when I execute the same tcpdump command on Linunx host.

```
C:\Users\mne\Desktop\plink.exe -ssh -pw XZY root@somehost.com "tcpdump -i any 'port 5000'" -w - | "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe" -k -i -
```

This is how the output looks like:

[image]

---

Could any one help me to get the HTTP data in Wireshark to be able to analyze them?

---

## UPDATE

I export the output of *dumptcp* to a file (where I can clearly see HTTP requests body and header). I tried to open that file in Wireshark, but Wireshark was **UNABLE** to display the HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireshark doesn't automatically treat this connection as HTTP because it was on TCP port 5000, which isn't a commonly used port for HTTP traffic.

To have Wireshark interpret it as HTTP traffic anyway, right click on one of the response packets, choose **Decode as...** and then select **HTTP** from the list.